# Swift Async method

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I'my studying asynchronous method right now and trying some code.

I learned that if you don't designate, all your x-code codes are executed on main-thread.

When you designated some task in async, that codes will be executed asynchronously.

That situation might be downloading from network such a heavy file because it may cause ui-update slow.

I understand the situation. But now I have a problem.

codes below is downloading songBytes from url and the final goal is update download progress view.

```
func downloadSongBytes(at url: URL, progress: Binding<Float>) async throws {
let (asyncBytes, response) = try await session.bytes(from: url)

let contentLength = Float(response.expectedContentLength)
var data = Data(capacity: Int(contentLength))


for try await byte in asyncBytes {
  data.append(byte)
  
  let currentProgress = Float(data.count) / contentLength
 
  if Int(progress.wrappedValue * 100) != Int(currentProgress * 100) {
    progress.wrappedValue = currentProgress
  }
}
```

}

the firstline of this code,

are we waiting for try await session.bytes to finish?

then get the return value(asyncBytes) and execute downside?

In mainUIView file, I don't repeat(call) the func downloadSongBytes, but how can I get repeatedly asynBytes so that I can calculate currentProgress..?

**can someone tell me the whole progress of doing this?(total progress by a single line..)**

Comment: you may have to use `withTaskGroup` to `...get repeatedly asynBytes...`

Comment: What is the method `bytes(from:)`. Is that a method of `URLSession`?